# SQLite query using data from two tables

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables: stop_times and trips -- both tables share trip_id. I want to build a query so that I extract information from both tables using trip_id, but then "filter" that information based on something from the first table.

I came up with this to get my information without the "filtering":

```
SELECT stop_times.trip_id, stop_times.arrival_time, trips.route_id
FROM stop_times, trips
WHERE stop_times.trip_id = trips.trip_id;
```

This works fine, but then I try to "filter" using stop_id:

```
SELECT stop_times.trip_id, stop_times.arrival_time, trips.route_id
FROM stop_times, trips
WHERE stop_times.stop_id IN (SELECT stop_id 
                             FROM stop_times 
                             WHERE stop_id = '81');
```

but it merges information incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Why did you remove `WHERE stop_times.trip_id = trips.trip_id` from the second query? This *might* work.

```
SELECT stop_times.trip_id, stop_times.arrival_time, trips.route_id
FROM stop_times, trips
WHERE stop_times.trip_id = trips.trip_id
  AND stop_times.stop_id = 81;
```

But you'd be better off using ANSI join syntax.

```
SELECT stop_times.trip_id, stop_times.arrival_time, trips.route_id
FROM stop_times
INNER JOIN trips ON stop_times.trip_id = trips.trip_id
WHERE stop_times.stop_id = 81;
```

Comment: `... stop_times JOIN trips USING (trip_id) ...`